# Prove that $(a+by)x^k=(x^2+y^2)h(x,y)$ is impossible

Tags: polynomials

Suppose $h(x,y)$ is a polynomial in $x$ and $y$ with real coefficients, and $k\geq 0$ an integer. It is then impossible to find real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $(a+by)x^k = (x^2+y^2)h(x,y)$, except in the trivial case that $h$ is identically zero and $a=b=0$. I can prove this by writing either $$h(x,y)=\sum_{i=0}^nh_i(x) y^i$$ or $$ h(x,y)=\sum_{j=0}^m g_j(y)x^j$$ and then looking at various cases, $k=0, k=1, k\geq 2$, but I wonder if there is a better and quicker way to see that.

Comment: Isn't that simply because $x^2+y^2$ is irreducible in ${\mathbb R}[x,y]$, and does not divide $a+by$ or $x$ ?

Comment: yes you are right... my question is now how to quickly prove that $x^2+y^2$ is irreducible and does not divide $x$ or $a+by$. Doesn't one need to go through a similar reasoning?

Comment: In your first form the term $h_n(x)y^{n+2}$ must appear in $(x^2+y^2) h(x,y)$ and $n+2\geq 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: for fixed $x$ you can  divide by $x^{2}+y^{2}$ to see that $h(x,.)$ is a polynomial which tends to $0$ as $ y \to \pm \infty$. The only polynomial with this property is the zero polynomial.